# Show conversations in Layer (with Atlas) even if there are no messages

Tags: objective-c, sdk, layerkit

I am trying to show all conversations that have been created, even if a message was not sent.  However, I can't for the life of me figure it out.  I've hit a million dead ends.  Does anyone know if this is even possible?

Perhaps a more specific question that would help me answer it is: is it possible to get an LYRConversation object of an existing conversation with just the user id of the other participant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through their docs for hours I finally found this:

> If you create a conversation the recipient won't see it until the first message is sent. If you want to be able to create a conversation without any messages, use the Platform API.

[Source](https://support.layer.com/hc/en-us/articles/206258296-I-created-a-conversation-and-sent-a-message-using-the-mobile-SDK-but-the-recipients-never-saw-it-Why-) and [link to information about the Platform API](https://developer.layer.com/docs/platform)

Seems to me this should be better documented, but there it is.  Hope this helps someone!